# Django переход на страницу по primary key

Tags: python, django

Вообщем у меня есть страница с марками машин и мне нужно чтобы при клике на определенную марку меня перекидывало на страницу со всеми машинами этой марки. Все данные я в таблицы внес, почему-то на этапе перехода на страницу никак не могу правильно написать:

```
class Marks(models.Model): // models
    mark = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.mark

class Cars(models.Model):
    CarName = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    mark = models.ForeignKey(Marks, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.CarName



def marks_list(request): // views
   marks = Marks.objects.all()
   return render(request, 'cars.html', {'marks':marks})

def specific_car(request, pk):
    Car = Cars.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'car_detail.html', {'cars': Car})




    urlpatterns = [
   path('marks/', marks_list), // urls
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('marks/<pk>', specific_car)
]





{% for mark in marks %} // cars.html
<div>
    <a href="{{mark.cars}}">
        {{mark.mark}}</a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

В файле car_detail.html у меня выводяться названия машин той или иной марки. Как мне правильно посылаться с файла cars.html чтобы открывать названия машин той или иной марки. Проект Называется cars и одно приложение которое там есть это car_marks

Answer (score 1):

Пойдём по порядку:

### Создаем прокет

Думаю, тут сложностей не будет:

```
pip install django
```

```
django-admin startapp CarShop .
```

```
python manage.py startapp mainapp
```

Добавляем приложение в список:

**CarShop/settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'mainapp'
]
```

---

### Создаём модели

**mainapp/models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Mark(models.Model):  # Название моделей принято писать в единственном числе
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)  # У марки должно быть имя (name), а не mark


class Car(models.Model):
    # Для того, чтобы удобно обращаться к машинам марки (например mark.cars.all) нужно указать related_name
    mark = models.ForeignKey(Mark, on_delete=models.Case, related_name='cars')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Проводим миграции:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Заполняем базу данными. Для этого можно воспользоваться специальной консольной оболочкой django:

```
python manage.py shell
```

```
>>> from mainapp.models import Mark, Car
>>>
>>>
>>> Mark(name='mark1').save()
>>> Mark(name='mark2').save()
>>> Mark(name='mark3').save()
>>>
>>>
>>> Car(mark_id=1, name='car1').save()
>>> Car(mark_id=1, name='car2').save()
>>> Car(mark_id=2, name='car3').save()
>>> Car(mark_id=2, name='car4').save()
>>> Car(mark_id=3, name='car5').save()
>>> Car(mark_id=3, name='car6').save()
```

---

### Создаём urls

Создаём `mainapp/urls.py`

**mainapp/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from mainapp import views as mainapp

app_name = 'mainapp'

urlpatterns = [
    path('marks/', mainapp.marks_list, name='mark_list'),  # создаём ссылку на список марок
    path('marks/mark/<int:mark_id>/', mainapp.mark_detail, name='mark_detail')  # создаём ссылку на просмотр конкретной марки
]
```

Подключаем его в корневом диспетчере url:

**CarShop/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('mainapp.urls', namespace='main'))  # Для удобства создаём namespace для приложения
]
```

---

### Создаём views

**mainapp/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from mainapp.models import Mark


def marks_list(request):
    return render(request, 'mainapp/marks.html', {'marks': Mark.objects.all()})


def mark_detail(request, mark_id: int):
    return render(request, 'mainapp/mark_detail.html', {'mark': Mark.objects.get(id=mark_id)})  # Получаем объект марки по id и передаем в шаблон
```

---

### Создаём шаблоны

Наши шаблоны должны храниться по такому пути: `mainapp/templates/mainapp/`:
Создаём `mainapp/templates/mainapp/marks.html`. В нём будет список всех марок

**mainapp/templates/mainapp/marks.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Марки</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for mark in marks %}
        <!-- Применяем url и передаём ей имя ссылки (main - namespace ; mark_detail - name) и id марки -->

        <!-- CarShop/urls.py -->
        <!-- path('', include('mainapp.urls', namespace='main')) -->

        <!-- mainapp/urls.py -->
        <!-- path('marks/mark/<int:mark_id>/', mainapp.mark_detail, name='mark_detail') -->

        <a href="{% url 'main:mark_detail' mark_id=mark.pk %}">{{ mark.name.capitalize }}</a>
        
        <!-- mark_id в будущем передастся в view -->
        
        <!-- mainapp/views.py -->
        <!-- def mark_detail(request, mark_id: int): -->
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Создаём `mainapp/templates/mainapp/mark_detail.html`. В нём будет описание и список машин марки

**mainapp/templates/mainapp/mark_detail.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ mark.name }}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Машины:</p>
    <ul>
        {% for car in mark.cars.all %}  <!-- Берём все машины марки и выводим -->
            <li>{{ car.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <a href="{% url 'main:mark_list' %}">Назад к списку марок</a>  <!-- По аналогии с marts.html передаём namespace и name ссылки -->
</body>
</html>
```

---

### Итоговая структура

[image: Структура]

---

### Запускаем сервер

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```